# CSS scrolling issue in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to solve this weird problem with scrolling in my website. The scrolling works fine when viewed on a Desktop Computer. However, it doesn't work in mobile phones. Do, I need to use some javascript to solve this issue?Or, can it be done just with CSS.

Here is my CSS snippet :

```
#popup-div{
   height: 100%;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` try adding this css

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflowscrolling.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vitorino but unfortunately it did not work. But I was able to make the scrollable work by adding a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isTouchDevice(){
        try{
            document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
            return true;
        }catch(e){
            return false;
        }
}

    function touchScroll(id){
        if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
            var el=document.getElementById(id);
            var scrollStartPos=0;

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
                scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            },false);

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
                this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            },false);
        }
    }

    //On page load
    touchScroll('popup-div');
```

Chris has shown a best working example
http://chrismbarr.github.io/TouchScroll/